# Inno Download Plugin: skip download if not exists...?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-download-plugin

How to skip automatically a download if the url doesn't exists or there isn't internet connection...?
Thanks in advance & cheers... ;-)

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    idpAddFile('http://127.0.0.1/test1.zip', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\test1.zip'));
    idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring the Inno download plugin [documentation](https://github.com/Ardutronico/inno-download-plugin/blob/master/doc/reference.lua) I think the best possible way is to try and check if the url/file exists and if it does then add it to the download list. According to the docs the `idpGetFileSize` gets the size of the file given in the url and returns true if it was able to calculate the file size without fail. Try this...

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
var 
    size: Int64;
begin
    if idpGetFileSize('http://127.0.0.1/test1.zip', size) then
        idpAddFile('http://127.0.0.1/test1.zip', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\test1.zip'));
    idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;
```

Comment: Works perfect... Thanks so much...! Regards... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Looking in download plugin [documentation](https://github.com/Ardutronico/inno-download-plugin/blob/master/doc/reference.lua) I found this option that works too:

```css
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    idpSetOption('ErrorDialog',  'none');
    idpAddFile('http://127.0.0.1/test1.zip', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\test1.zip'));
    idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;
```

Comment: Cool. Use the best one which suits your use case ;)

Comment: You will hide any errors this way. Looks like a bad solution to me. @Sam's solution is the correct one.